# how to define a rpm spec macro with empty body?

Tags: rpm, specifications

the problem is quite easy to exhibit:

```
rpm --eval "%define xyz"
error: Macro %xyz has empty body
```

i want to get the patch_level and echo_dist may return sles11 or sles11sp1, for sle1s11 i just want the patch_level to be an empty string, but that leads to the empty body error.

```
rpm --eval "%{expand: %%define patch_level %(echo_dist | sed -e "s/sles11//")}
```

i am not fully understand the rpm spec file, any suggestion to the problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
%define xyz %{nil}
```

Comment: i think this should be the answer. althou not test by myself yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
%define xyz %100
```

supposed to expand to the 100's parameter to the macro which will be empty.